# Python sequence generator

Tags: python, sequence

Hello and thanks for your time to read my question, before all.

I am currently creating a python generator so it would help my main work...
I am pretending to get a sequence where only the number changes:

Code:

```
numbers = range(0, 170)

sequence_of_numbers = []
for number in numbers:
   if number < 170:
      sequence_of_numbers.append(number)


print("color " + sequence_of_numbers + " = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);")
```

What I want to get:

```
color1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
color2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
color3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
color4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
color5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
```

and so on...

The question is:
How do i fix this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File https://extendsclass.com/lib/Brython-3.8.9/www/src/Lib/site-packages/editor.py, line 116, in run
    exec(src, ns)
  File <string>, line 9, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert list to str implicitly
```

Comment: What are you expecting for a result?  You can't concatenate a string and a list.  You likely need to create your expected string from the list values -- but without a specification of your desired result, there's no way we can reasonably lead you to output formatting, `join`, or other string processing.

I suggest that you review the documentation for those techniques.

Comment: You're trying to print a `list` as a string. If you want to print the index associated with each item you can use `enumerate` and start at `1`. But I'm not sure what good printing that information does for you

Comment: Change `print("color " + sequence_of_numbers + " = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);")` to `print("color " + str(sequence_of_numbers) + " = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I just realized you're probably printing things out for use in C# or another language.
You can do something like this:

```py
for i in range(1, 170):
    print(f"color{i} = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);")
```

There's no reason to actually store another list since you're not using it. You can instead just iterate over a normal `range`. In this case it will use 1,2,3, ..., 169.

Comment: for i in range(1, 170):
    print("color" + str(i) + " = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);")

So simple... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just noticed this.

you are appending your numbers to a list and essentially trying to print them out all at once, using a for iteration loop this can be avoided.

```
numbers = range(0, 170)

sequence_of_numbers = []
for number in numbers:
   if number < 170:
      sequence_of_numbers.append(number)

for x in range(len(sequence_of_numbers)):
   print("color " + str(sequence_of_numbers[x]) + " = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);")
```

:)